# Replacing Damaged Power Lines

Tags: mains

Why aren't power lines replaced when a large tree lands on them? It seems to me the wires have been stretched, thereby decreasing their diameter and increasing their resistance.

Comment: It might "seem to you", but in practice, that is not the case.

Comment: @DaveTweed congrats on breaking the 100K mark

Comment: Cost saving? ;)

Comment: Because fixing things that aren't broken costs money.

Answer (score 2):

Power lines that are low enough where trees can fall on them have a steel cable for mechanical support.  When a tree falls, the steel cable takes the load.  It will elongate slightly and put a little more tension on the conducting wires, but not a lot.

The steel cables are often strong enough that the wooden pole holding the span at either end breaks before the cable when something sufficiently heavy falls on the cable.

Around here (north central Massachusetts), local feeders are often 13.8 kV three phase.  These are in a bundle of 4 wires, with the steel support cable being the top, and the three conducting cables on spacers hung from the steel cable.  The top steel cable also acts as lightning protection.  It is grounded regularly.